# Scraping hidden elements in a dynamically changing html

Tags: python, selenium, beautifulsoup

I need to scrape some information from a dynamically changing html. The website in question is :
https://www.mitartlending.com/featuredartworks. Here, when you click on a given image and hover your mouse over the enlarged image a text overlay pops up. I am trying to scrape that text. After trying to do this with BS I decided that I am going to have to probably use selenium. How would you go about about solving this problem? So far, I have:

```
from selenium import webdriver
driver = webdriver.Chrome('/Users/Abramo/SeleniumDrivers/chromedriver') 
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
driver.get('https://www.mitartlending.com/featuredartworks')

driver.implicitly_wait(3)

my_element = driver.find_element_by_xpath(f'/html/body/div[5]/div[2]/div/main/section/div/div/div/div[3]/div/div/div/div[1]/div/a/img')
my_element.click()                                        
   

copy_from = driver.find_element_by_class_name('sqs-lightbox-meta overlay-description-visible')
my_next_button = driver.find_element_by_class_name('sqs-lightbox-next')
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The data is all there within attributes. You just need to extract the appropriate ones. No need for the overhead of selenium.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs

r = requests.get('https://www.mitartlending.com/featuredartworks')
soup = bs(r.content, 'lxml')
results = {i['data-title']:' '.join(bs(i['data-description'], 'lxml').text.split('\n')) for i in soup.select('.margin-wrapper > a')}
print(results)
```

Comment: can I ask  what ">a" means in '.margin-wrapper > a' ?

Comment: It's a css selector syntax. element with class name `margin-wrapper` immediatelly followed by element with tag name `a`

Comment: ^^ except the `a` is a direct child of the element with class `margin-wrapper`

Answer (score 0):

You can locate any of those images by

```
images = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//img[contains(@class,'thumb-image loaded')]')
```

So, for example to click on the second image you can with

```
images[1].click()
```

To hover over the element you can do this:

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains

hover = ActionChains(driver).move_to_element(images[1])
hover.perform()
```

Now, when the text is appeared you can locate and get it with

```
text = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('(//img[contains(@class,'thumb-image loaded')])[2]/..//p').text
```

The same can be done for any other image there.
Altogether the code will look like:

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains

images = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//img[contains(@class,"thumb-image loaded")]')
images[1].click()

time.sleep(2)
hover = ActionChains(driver).move_to_element(images[1])
hover.perform()

time.sleep(2)
text = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('(//img[contains(@class,"thumb-image loaded")])[2]/..//p')
for t in text:
    print(t.text)
```

I added sleeps just to make it simply while it's preferred to use expected conditions waits instead